# Incremental "auto save" in ArcMap edit session

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, editing

Is there any way to add automatic incremental saving to ArcMap 10.1 editing sessions?  I found [this script](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14896) for 9.x but it doesn't seem to work with the newer versions.  I'm looking for a script or add on. I'm more concerned with saving edits rather than saving the mxd itself.

Frequent crashes have ruined my morning too often.

I'm aware that this is similar to [Does ArcGIS for Desktop have auto-backup feature?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59851/does-arcgis-10-1-have-a-auto-backup-feature), but it is not exactly the same in my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

I am not aware of an ArcMap editing solution but recommend you add your voice to this [ArcGIS Idea to "Add an autosave feature for ArcGIS Desktop"](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=0873000000086ueAAA) which covers auto-saving both data edits and map document changes.

At ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop, the ArcGIS Pro application can be set to [Automatically save edits](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/basics/customize-how-you-save-edits.htm):

> To enable and set automatic saves, check the Automatically save edits
>   check box and set the Time interval (minutes) or Number of operations.

Answer (score 1):

As of 10.4 there is apparently an interface  IEditProperties5.AutoSaveNonVersionedEdit that can be used to switch on auto save for non versioned data set. [https://geonet.esri.com/thread/105459#comment-397138](http://ersir%20reply)